# Difference between CC_REF_PTR_SAFE_RETAIN and CC_SAFE_RETAIN in cocos2D-x

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

What is the difference between CC_REF_PTR_SAFE_RETAIN  and CC_SAFE_RETAIN in cocos2D-x? and when to use them ?

Comment: What version of cocos2d-x are you using? I can't find `CC_REF_PTR_SAFE_RETAIN`...

Comment: i m using cocos2d-x v3.2 , ... search for header where CC_SAFE_RELEASE is declared , you will find they others. (CCRefPtr.h)
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CC_REF_PTR_SAFE_RETAIN` allows for calling `retain()` on a `const cocos2d::Ref*` object, while `CC_SAFE_RETAIN` is for non-`const` `cocos2d::Ref*` objects only.

E.g.

```
cocos2d::Ref* obj = <some object>;
const cocos2d::Ref* kObj = <some constant object>;
CC_SAFE_RETAIN(obj); // OK
CC_SAFE_RETAIN(kObj); // Member function 'retain' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const cocos2d::Ref', but function is not marked const
CC_REF_PTR_SAFE_RETAIN(obj); // OK
CC_REF_PTR_SAFE_RETAIN(kObj); // OK
```